# How to disable customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account

is there a basic functionality to disable a customer?
Or do I need to implement by myself?

Comment: You can use Disable Customer developed by "STee" to easily deactivate a customer access on the frontend website, and ofcourse you can always reactivate them. Once deactivated, no data will be erased from the customer account.
https://marketplace.magento.com/stee-disable-customer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not in Magento out of the box.

But Vinai Kopp was so kind to build a module for this and opensource it. You can download it from the Github page: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

Comment: thx for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not **have this type of feature**.

**You need to do customization yourself.** or  any use 3-party extension.

Comment: thx for the info!

Comment: you  r welcome....